# In React, How to Return JSX together with JS Function that returns more JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In a React Component that renders a select field with options being dynamically created by a component function `renderOptions()`, how can we also render an empty `option` element (eg: `<option value=""></option>`) as the very first option?

**React Code before adding the empty `<option>`**

```
renderOptions() {
    return (
        this.props.users.map(user => (
            <option key={ user._id } value={ user._id }>{ user.name }</option>
        ))
    )
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="someDiv"></div>

            <select>
                { this.props.usersAreLoading 
                    ? <option value="">Loading...</option> 
                    : this.renderOptions()
                }            
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Failed Attempt**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="someDiv"></div>

            <select>
                { this.props.usersAreLoading 
                    ? <option value="">Loading...</option> 
                    : <option value=""></option> this.renderOptions()
                }            
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <select>
        { this.props.usersAreLoading 
                && <option value="">Loading...</option> }
        {!this.props.usersAreLoading && <option value=""></option>} 
        {!this.props.usersAreLoading && this.renderOptions()}           
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to render it separately:

```
{!this.props.usersAreLoading && <option value=""></option>}

{this.props.usersAreLoading 
  ? <option value="">Loading...</option> 
  : this.renderOptions()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (maybe not the most elegant) is to use two conditions

```
        <select>
            { this.props.usersAreLoading 
                ? <option value="">Loading...</option> 
                : <option value=""></option>
            } 
           {!this.props.usersAreLoading && this.renderOptions()
      } 

        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ternary 'else' should contain multiple elements, they could be wrapped with `React.Fragment`:

```
{this.props.usersAreLoading ? (
  <option value="">Loading...</option>
) : (
  <>
    <option value=""></option>
    {this.renderOptions()}
  </>
)}
```

Or provided as single array:

```
{this.props.usersAreLoading ? (
  <option value="">Loading...</option>
) : [
  <option value=""></option>,
  this.renderOptions()
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragment to wrap the option components

```
<select>
          {this.props.usersAreLoading ? (
            <option value="">Loading...</option>
          ) : (
            <Fragment>
                <option value=""/>
              {this.renderOptions()}
            </Fragment>
          )}
          )} }
 </select>
```